# Beanutils Unknown property on class: pinkyMoreAndMore works pMoreAndMore not

Tags: java, lombok, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm copying bean/pojo values from one bean to another bean.

Beanutils does the job nicely.

This morning i bumped into a property which caused a

```
Unknown property on class
```

exception.

The name of the property was "pMoreAndMore", getters and setters were generated by trusty lombok like getPMoreAndMore()

I tried to copy values using the following property name "pMoreAndMore", but this caused above exception.

Did a bit of searching online but didn't find much, so i renamed my property to "pinkyMoreAndMore" (with a generate getter like getPinkyMoreAndMore()) and used property name "pinkyMoreAndMore" to do the value copying with beanutils.

No problem here.

Why would "pinkyMoreAndMore" work but "pMoreAndMore" cause an error?
Might this be an edge case when it comes to camelcase and such?

Comment: can you test with `PMoreAndMore` ? i have somewhere else bumped to a situation where the lombok getter default name is not what some bean util stuff expects. Or instruct lombok to generate setter like `getpMoreAndMore`, `getPmoreAndMore`? just to see if it is the case.

Comment: @pirho I did give "PMoreAndMore" a shot and that one works. Quite strange, i think you are right that there is a incompatibility between lombok and beanutils on these cases. Good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java bean specification is a bit more peculiar that people commongly think:

```
property - getter
-----------------
      aa - getaa()
      aA - getaA()
      Aa - getaa()
      AA - getAA()
```

According to [specification](http://java.sun.com/products/javabeans/docs/beans.101.pdf) the getter for `pMoreAndMore` should be named `getpMoreAndMore()`. This is what BeanUtils expect. The fact that Lombok follow some common delusion about property accessors naming should be considered a bug.

Please refer to the following article [Java Tip #6 - Don't capitalize first two letters of a bean property name](http://futuretask.blogspot.com.by/2005/01/java-tip-6-dont-capitalize-first-two.html) for longer and more detailed explanation.

Comment: Cheers @Aleh . I've created a issue at the lombok github: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1496